# Javascript inside LD JSON

Tags: javascript, json, json-ld

I'm wondering if it's possible to execute some javascript inside an ld+json script. For example "window.location.hostname"

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "WebSite",
   "url": "http://" + window.location.hostname
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, scripts of the type "application/ld+json" won't be executed. But, you could do something like this:

```
<script>
  var el = document.createElement('script');
  el.type = 'application/ld+json';
  el.text = JSON.stringify({
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "http://" + window.location.hostname
  });
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el);
</script>
```

Comment: What are the use cases for using JSON-LD?